# Understanding ReactiveCocoa and MVVM in my ReactiveCocoa test project

Tags: ios, mvvm, reactive-cocoa

I've written a very simple ReactiveCocoa test application to try my hand at coding in RAC (rather than just reading about it endlessly). It's on [Github](https://github.com/cbowns/RACTest), and I wanted to get some specific questions about it answered. I'll link to the code components as I go along.

First, a brief explanation of the application: it's a timer-driven iteration counter that can be paused by the user. (Its purpose is to count how many seconds have elapsed, eliding the ones where the user paused it.) Once a second, a timer increments a variable iff the user hasn't paused the incrementing behaviour.

There are three classes I'm concerned about hearing feedback for:

- [MPSTicker](https://github.com/cbowns/RACTest/blob/4b8491101ab55712e914171e6ccd263f753bd161/RACTest/MPSTicker.h) ([.m](https://github.com/cbowns/RACTest/blob/4b8491101ab55712e914171e6ccd263f753bd161/RACTest/MPSTicker.m)), which performs "accumulate since initialization unless paused" and provides that result on a signal. It has a public `BOOL` property to control whether or not accumulation is running.
- [MPSViewModel](https://github.com/cbowns/RACTest/blob/4b8491101ab55712e914171e6ccd263f753bd161/RACTest/MPSViewModel.h) ([.m](https://github.com/cbowns/RACTest/blob/4b8491101ab55712e914171e6ccd263f753bd161/RACTest/MPSViewModel.m)), which provides a ViewModel wrapping from `MPSTicker` to the view controller. It provides read-only strings which show the number of ticks and show the text for the action which, if taken, "pauses" or "resumes" ticks. It also has a read-write `BOOL` for pausing/unpausing ticks.
- [MPSViewController](https://github.com/cbowns/RACTest/blob/4b8491101ab55712e914171e6ccd263f753bd161/RACTest/MPSViewController.h) ([.m](https://github.com/cbowns/RACTest/blob/4b8491101ab55712e914171e6ccd263f753bd161/RACTest/MPSViewController.m)), which consumes strings from `MPSViewModel` by binding a label to the ViewModel's tick string, binding a button's text to the "tick action" string, and mapping a button's press into the ViewModel's paused property.

My questions:

1. I don't like the [`BOOL` property on `MPSTicker`](https://github.com/cbowns/RACTest/blob/4b8491101ab55712e914171e6ccd263f753bd161/RACTest/MPSTicker.h#L22) for enabling/disabling its accumulation, but I didn't know how to do it more Reactive-ly. (This also runs downstream to the ViewModel and ViewController: how can I run a string through all three of these to control whether or not the ticker is running?)
2. The ViewModel exposes [`tickString`](https://github.com/cbowns/RACTest/blob/4b8491101ab55712e914171e6ccd263f753bd161/RACTest/MPSViewModel.h#L19) and [`tickStateString`](https://github.com/cbowns/RACTest/blob/4b8491101ab55712e914171e6ccd263f753bd161/RACTest/MPSViewModel.h#L22) as very traditional properties, but the ViewController which consumes these immediately maps them back into [text on a label](https://github.com/cbowns/RACTest/blob/4b8491101ab55712e914171e6ccd263f753bd161/RACTest/MPSViewController.m#L73) and [button text](https://github.com/cbowns/RACTest/blob/4b8491101ab55712e914171e6ccd263f753bd161/RACTest/MPSViewController.m#L76) with `RACObserve`. This feels wrong, but I don't know how to expose a signal from the ViewModel that's easy for the ViewController to consume for these two attributes.
3. The ViewController suffers an [indignity](https://github.com/cbowns/RACTest/blob/4b8491101ab55712e914171e6ccd263f753bd161/RACTest/MPSViewController.m#L82) when flipping the `paused` `BOOL` on the ViewModel. I think this is another downstream effect of #1, "This shouldn't be a `BOOL` property", but I'm not sure

(Notes: I think I shied away from a signal for the `BOOL` of `paused` on `MPSTicker` because I didn't know how to consume it in the ViewModel to derive two strings (one for the current tick count, and one for the action text), nor how to push UI-driven value changes when the user pushes the "pause" or "resume" button. This is my core concern in questions 1 and 3.)

Some screenshots to help you visualize this gorgeous design:

**Ticking:**

[image: Ticking]

**Paused:**

[image: Paused]

Comment: For those following along at home, the [unit test party for this app has begun](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21565736/unit-testing-a-simple-usage-of-racsignal-with-racsubject)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is such an awesome write-up!

> I don't like the BOOL property on MPSTicker for enabling/disabling its accumulation, but I didn't know how to do it more Reactive-ly. (This also runs downstream to the ViewModel and ViewController: how can I run a string through all three of these to control whether or not the ticker is running?)

Broadly, there's nothing wrong or non-Reactive about using properties. KVO-able properties can be thought of as behaviors in the academic FRP sense: they're signals which have a value at all points in their lifetime. In fact, in Objective-C properties can be even better than signals because they preserve type information that we'd otherwise lose by wrapping it in a `RACSignal`.

So there's nothing wrong with using KVO-able properties if it's the right tool for the job. Just tilt your head, squint a bit, and they look like signals.

Whether something should be a property or `RACSignal` is more about the semantics you're trying to capture. Do you *need* the properties (ha!) of a property, or do you care more about the general idea of a value changing over time?

In the specific case of `MPSTicker`, I'd argue the transitions of `accumulateEnabled` are really the thing you care about.

So if `MPSTicker` had a `accumulationEnabledSignal` property, we'd do something like:

```
_accumulateSignal = [[[[RACSignal 
    combineLatest:@[ _tickSignal, self.accumulationEnabledSignal ]] 
    filter:^(RACTuple *t) {
        NSNumber *enabled = t[1];
        return enabled.boolValue;
    }] 
    reduceEach:^(NSNumber *tick, NSNumber *enabled) {
        return tick;    
    }] 
    scanWithStart:@(0) reduce:^id(NSNumber *previous, id next) {
        // On each tick, we add one to the previous value of the accumulate signal.
        return @(previous.unsignedIntegerValue + 1);
    }];
```

We're combining both the tick and the enabledness, since it's the transitions of both that drive our logic.

(FWIW, `RACCommand` is similar and uses an enabled signal: https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/9503c6ef7f2f327f4db6440ddfbc4ee09b86857f/ReactiveCocoaFramework/ReactiveCocoa/RACCommand.h#L95.)

> The ViewModel exposes tickString and tickStateString as very traditional properties, but the ViewController which consumes these immediately maps them back into text on a label and button text with RACObserve. This feels wrong, but I don't know how to expose a signal from the ViewModel that's easy for the ViewController to consume for these two attributes.

I may be missing your point here, but I think what you've described is fine. This goes back to the above point about the relationship between properties and signals.

With RAC and MVVM, a lot of the code is simply threading data through to other parts of the app, transforming it as needed in its particular context. It's about the flow of data through the app. It's boring—almost mechanical—but that's kinda the point. The less we have to re-invent or handle in an ah hoc way, the better.

FWIW, I'd change the implementation slightly:

```
RAC(self, tickString) = [[[[_ticker 
    accumulateSignal] 
    deliverOn:[RACScheduler mainThreadScheduler]]
    // Start with 0.
    startWith:@(0)]
    map:^(NSNumber *tick) {
        // Unpack the value and format our string for the UI.
        NSUInteger count = tick.unsignedIntegerValue;
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i tick%@ since launch", count, (count != 1 ? @"s" : @"")];
    }];
```

That way we're more explicitly defining the relationship of `tickString` to some transformation of `ticker` (and we can avoid doing the strong/weak `self` dance).

> The ViewController suffers an indignity when flipping the paused BOOL on the ViewModel. I think this is another downstream effect of #1, "This shouldn't be a BOOL property", but I'm not sure

I'm probably just missing it due to tiredness, but what's the indignity you have in mind here?

Comment: This is all fantastic, especially "With RAC and MVVM, a lot of the code is simply threading data through to other parts of the app, transforming it as needed in its particular context. It's about the flow of data through the app. It's boring—almost mechanical—but that's kinda the point. The less we have to re-invent or handle in an ah hoc way, the better." It makes sense to think about the data representations in isolation, from the ticker to the viewmodel, and separately, from the viewmodel to the view/controller. (Or, "Just because you *can* run a signal across doesn't mean you *have* to.")

Comment: Re: ViewController indignity, I believe I was thinking that it seemed weird to flip a BOOL for something that felt very signal-ish, but it makes sense now, especially with your comments about the MVVM divide and properties vs. signals.

Comment: Actually, a better question about `accumulationEnabledSignal`: I know how to structure the basic signal in the Ticker, but I'm not sure how to decide what input to take from the outside world (that's analog to the enabled BOOL) to control its value. Do I publish the `accumulationEnabledSignal` and let clients push values into it, or do I expose the enabled BOOL or some other signal?

Comment: Have the client give you `accumulationEnabledSignal`, ideally as an argument to the initializer.

Comment: Ah, perfect, that's what I'd figured out in my noodling around yesterday. Thanks!