# Unit-testing a simple usage of RACSignal with RACSubject

Tags: unit-testing, reactive-cocoa

(I may be using this in a totally incorrect manner, so feel free to challenge the premise of this post.)

I have a small [RACTest app](https://github.com/cbowns/RACTest) ([sound familiar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21419864/understanding-reactivecocoa-and-mvvm-in-my-very-likely-poorly-architected-test)) that I'm trying to unit test. I'd like to test [MPSTicker](https://github.com/cbowns/RACTest/blob/fdb9f65e5b139ee3a8711140064f9e6d8eb44e25/Shared%20Components/MPSTicker.h), one of the most ReactiveCocoa-based components. It has a signal that sends a value once per second that accumulates, iff an accumulation flag is set to YES. I [added an initializer](https://github.com/cbowns/RACTest/blob/fdb9f65e5b139ee3a8711140064f9e6d8eb44e25/Shared%20Components/MPSTicker.h#L21) to take a custom signal for its incrementing signal, rather than being only timer-based.

I wanted to unit test a couple of behaviours of MPSTicker:

- Verify that its accumulation signal increments properly (i.e. monotonically increases) when accumulation is enabled and the input incrementing signal sends a new value.
- Verify that it sends the same value (and not an incremented value) when the input signal sends a value.

I've added [a test that uses the built-in timer to test the first increment](https://github.com/cbowns/RACTest/blob/master/RACTestTests/MPSTickerTest.m#L75), and it works as I expected (though I'm seeking advice on improving the goofy RACSequence initialization I did to get a signal with the `@(1)` value I wanted.)

I've had a very difficult time figuring out what input signal I can provide to MPSTicker that I can manually send values to. I'm envisioning a test like:

```
<set up ticker>
<send a tick value>
<verify accumulated value is 1>
<send another value>
<verify accumulated value is 2>
```

I tried using a `RACSubject` so I can use `sendNext:` to push in values as I see fit, but it's not working like I expect. Here's two broken tests:

```
- (void)testManualTimerTheFirst
{
    // Create a custom tick with one value to send.
    RACSubject *controlledSignal = [RACSubject subject];
    MPSTicker *ticker = [[MPSTicker alloc] initWithTickSource:controlledSignal];
    [ticker.accumulateSignal subscribeNext:^(id x) {
        NSLog(@"%s value is %@", __func__, x);
    }];

    [controlledSignal sendNext:@(2)];
}

- (void)testManualTimerTheSecond
{
    // Create a custom tick with one value to send.
    RACSubject *controlledSignal = [RACSubject subject];
    MPSTicker *ticker = [[MPSTicker alloc] initWithTickSource:controlledSignal];

    BOOL success = NO;
    NSError *error = nil;
    id value = [ticker.accumulateSignal asynchronousFirstOrDefault:nil success:&success error:&error];

    if (!success) {
        XCTAssertTrue(success, @"Signal failed to return a value. Error: %@", error);
    } else {
        XCTAssertNotNil(value, @"Signal returned a nil value.");
        XCTAssertEqualObjects(@(1), value, @"Signal returned an unexpected value.");
    }

    // Send a value.
    [controlledSignal sendNext:@(1)];
}
```

In `testManualTimerTheFirst`, I never see any value from `controlledSignal`'s `sendNext:` come through to my `subscribeNext:` block.

In `testManualTimerTheSecond`, I tried using the `asynchronousFirstOrDefault:` call to get the first value from the signal, then manually sent a value on my subject, but the value didn't come through, and the test failed when `asynchronousFirstOrDefault:` timed out.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6):

This may not answer your question exactly, but it may give you insights on how to effectively test your signals. I've used 2 approaches myself so far:

**XCTestCase and TRVSMonitor**

[TRVSMonitor](https://github.com/travisjeffery/TRVSMonitor) is a small utility which will pause the current thread for you while you run your assertions. For example:

```
TRVSMonitor *monitor = [TRVSMonitor monitor];

[[[self.service searchPodcastsWithTerm:@"security now"] collect] subscribeNext:^(NSArray *results) {
    XCTAssertTrue([results count] > 0, @"Results count should be > 0";
    [monitor signal];

} error:^(NSError *error) {
    XCTFail(@"%@", error);
    [monitor signal];
}];

[monitor wait];
```

As you can see, I'm telling the monitor to wait right after I subscribe and signal it to stop waiting at the end of subscribeNext and error blocks to make it continue executing (so other tests can run too). This approach has the **benefit of not relying on a static timeout**, so your code can run as long as it needs to.

Using CocoaPods, you can easily add TRVSMonitor to your project:

```
pod "TRVSMonitor", "~> 0.0.3"
```

**Specta & Expecta**

[Specta](https://github.com/specta/specta) is a BDD/TDD (behavior driven/test driven) test framework. Expecta is a framework which provides more convenient assertion matchers. It has built-in support for async tests. It enables you to write more descriptive tests with ReactiveCocoa, like so:

```
it(@"should return a valid image, with cache state 'new'", ^AsyncBlock {
    [[cache imageForURL:[NSURL URLWithString:SECURITY_NOW_ARTWORK_URL]] subscribeNext:^(UIImage *image) {
        expect(image).notTo.beNil();
        expect(image.cacheState).to.equal(JPImageCacheStateNew);

    } error:^(NSError *error) {
        XCTFail(@"%@", error);

    } completed:^{
        done();
    }];
});
```

Note the use of **^AsyncBlock {**. Using simply **^ {** would imply a synchronous test.

Here you call the done() function to signal the end of an asynchronous test. I believe Specta uses a 10 second timeout internally.

Using CocoaPods, you can easily add Expecta & Specta:

```
pod "Expecta", "~> 0.2.3"
pod "Specta", "~> 0.2.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19127547/420594

The [XCAsyncTestCase](https://github.com/premosystems/XCAsyncTestCase) has some extra functionality to allow for asynchronous test cases.

Also, I haven't looked at it in depth yet, but could [ReactiveCocoaTests](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/tree/master/ReactiveCocoaFramework/ReactiveCocoaTests) be of some interest to you? On a glance, they appear to be using Expecta.